# Qt keep translate in QApplication

Tags: qt

I'm trying to store loaded translation in QApplication
I'm loading language this way

```
QTranslator translator;
QString dir = QApplication::applicationDirPath();
dir.append("/languages");
if(translator.load("main_pl.qm", dir))
    QApplication::installTranslator(&translator);
```

And then i'm trying to get translation this way:

```
QApplication::translate("accountTab", "Login completed!", 0)
```

Without success.
So i tried to load translation (same way as above) in function which later I'm translating - that worked.
Translation is working just in function which translation was loaded.
Any suggestion, how to make it working in all classes and function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you create a temporary translator that gets deleted as soon as you go out of your function's scope. In order to keep your translator object "alive" you need to allocate it from the heap. For example:

```
QTranslator *translator = new QTranslator;
QString dir = QApplication::applicationDirPath();
dir.append("/languages");
if(translator->load("main_pl.qm", dir)) {
    QApplication::installTranslator(translator);
}
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't pay attention to that pointer is sending to QApplication. Thank you for the answer :)